# Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Tags: php, php7

Descargué un documento por git el cual funciona correctamente y se muestra la pagina pero lo usan en linux , pero al descargarlo en mi pc me dice

> Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

el codigo es el siguente:

```
       public function generarCodigo($longitud) {
            $key = '';
            $pattern = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
            $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
            for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
            return $key;
    }
```

No se si sea un error por la version de php o por windows

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP tienes instalada? y ¿qué versión de PHP usa el script que te descargaste?

Comment: la version q usaron era 5.7  y yo uso la  7.4.8

Answer (score 6):

Primer comentario:

- Estás tratando de usar un script escrito en una versión obsoleta y abandonada de [PHP](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), dado eso sugiero revises si no existen mas *detalles por solucionar*
- Lo segundo, es que el fallo esta referido a este [rfc en PHP 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access) donde se propone:

> Eliminar la disponibilidad de uso de llaves`{}` tanto para poder acceder a elementos de un vector como de un string offset, con lo cual solo debe quedar el uso de `[]` como símbolo de acceso a los elementos.

Para pasar de una sintaxis así**:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump($arr{1});
```

A una que será de ahora en adelante así:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump($arr[1]);
```

** Ejemplo tomado de [este enlace](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access)

**Además** es importante notar (*como lo comparte @Marcos*), para versiones de PHP 8 en adelante, esto que ocurre pasará de *una advertencia de uso desaconsejado a un error en el compilador*, *para mayor referencia leer el apartado [Future Scope](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access#future_scope)*

Comment: Excelente uso de la documentación, BetaM.

Comment: Seria entonces mas recomendable usar la misma version de php? para evitar futuros errores de este estilo?

Comment: Lo ideal es que uses la última versión estable, pero es es *digamos*, por que depende que tanto debas cambiar del código fuente en si, como te digo lo mas recomendable sería revisa que mas detalles saltan, actualizalos si te es posible.

Comment: es que todo un sistema esta desarrollado en esa version y no me es posible actualizar el codigo , solo desarrollar lo que necesito .... donde podria conseguir esa version de php 5.6 para descargarla

Comment: Mira no se que tanto debas cambiar tu versión de PHP por una tan anterior, si esto es el único error obtenido entonces deja la versión que usas actualmente y solo has el cambio sugerido en la respuesta, si te empiezan a salir mas errores entonces deberás **considerar** migrar a una versión antigua de PHP, pero como digo si esto que preguntas es el único fallo entonces no tiene caso, solo cambia lo sugerido, ahora para encontrar alguna versión antigua de PHP puedes probar en la página oficial

Comment: muchas gracias ya logre acomodar el error gracias a los comentarios , vere si mas adelante es necesario cambiar de version

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, se soluciona cambiando `{}` por `[]`, esto como acceso a índice de array por ejemplo.

```
$pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
```

Reemplazarlo por:

```
$pattern[mt_rand(0,$max)];
```